# How to return the return index of the value using "awesomplete"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using "Awesomplete" from http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/#extensibility.
I can retrieve the selected value, but I need the index of this value.

Follow the code to return just the selected value.

```
document.getElementById('Search').addEventListener('awesomplete-selectcomplete',function(){
  console.log("value:" + this.value);
  console.log("index:" + this.index); //this doesn't work, it returns "undefined"
});
```

Comment: I don't know the context, but what do you think about using `indexOf`?

Comment: Here I found an alternative:`(var val = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var opts = document.getElementById('dlist').childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
      if (opts[i].value === val) {
        // An item was selected from the list!
        // yourCallbackHere()
        alert(opts[i].value);
        break;
      }
    })`

Comment: can you share your html part?

Comment: HTML DOM elements aren't from an array, so they don't have an `index` property. Not only does this mean you won't be able to get it that way, but even if you knew the number the element fell within a sequence, you couldn't interact with that element using that number, as it isn't indexed so that number won't mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

Since the return element is a HTMLInputElement, there no .index option, in this case you have to iterate the data-attrib, something like like this:

```
<input id="Search" class="awesomplete" data-list="Ada, Java, JavaScript, Brainfuck, LOLCODE, Node.js, Ruby on Rails" />
```

js:

```
document.getElementById('Search').addEventListener('awesomplete-selectcomplete',function(){

value = this.value;
data_list = this.getAttribute("data-list");
array_list = data_list.split(", "); // attention on whitespace remove.

array_list.forEach(function(element){
    i = array_list.indexOf(element); // clicked element index.
    if(element == value)
    console.log("index: " + "[" + i + "] " + element );

});
```